# Why does QFileInfo::isExecutable() return false for ".msi" files?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing an application using C++ and Qt and I need to know if an input file is executable.

I'm using `QFileInfo::isExecutable()` which behaves correctly for most files, except for those with the `.msi` extension, for which it returns false.

How can I figure out for sure if a file is executable or not? I need to do this in Qt for cross-compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know how `QFileInfo::isExecutable()` determines a file as executable:

- In Windows Qt just checks if the extension of file is `.exe`, `.com` and `.bat` without checking its content.
- In Unix-like systems, it checks the file's attribute and returns true for files which have execution permission.

So a `.msi` file isn't a executable file in view of Qt under Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a new condition, and I check manually the file's extension, to make sure it isn't `.msi`, `.msp` or other extensions that can be executed without the need of another application.

Comment: @zozermania: For the sake of correctness, msi files are _not_ executable. You _need_ another application to use msi files. That application is [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer). Sure, it is installed on Windows, but sometimes, especially with old computers and new software, you cannot install the msi installation packet before you update the Windows Installer to the latest version. And for example you cannot start msi files using QProcess without knowing that the actual application required is msiexec.exe.

Answer (score 5):

Well, an MSI file isn't actually executable. It's a document format used by the Windows Installer executable. So `QFileInfo` is correct.

What is the specific problem you need to solve? Why do you think knowing whether a file is executable will help you? What is the goal you have in mind? If you give us more information, we may be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I'm fixing a bug in an application that permits the user to input certain files. 
It's supposed to accept every file, except the executable ones, and I'm trying to find a method that works on both Windows and Linux, but if there isn't one, a Windows-only solution is ok too.

Comment: @M M. What do you mean? The answer is very accurate, .msi files are not executables any more than .txt files.

Comment: @Roku: It is irrelevant to **how** Qt determines executable files and will mislead people about it.

Comment: @M M. But then by your logic a simple text file in Linux is also an executable because double clicking it will start gedit.

Comment: @MM. I'm aware. That was my point--`msi` is not an extension used for executable files.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: True, You should mention it in your answer

Comment: No need. My answer does not discuss the implementation of `QFileInfo`, nor is it relevant.