# QFileInfo::isExecutable() returns false for ".exe" file

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qfileinfo

I'm trying to allow drag-and-drop of .exe unit test files into a `QMainWindow`. My `dragEnterEvent` looks like this:

```
void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *e)
{   
    if (e->mimeData()->hasUrls()) 
    {
        QFileInfo info(e->mimeData()->urls().first().fileName()); // this works
        if (info.isExecutable())   // false for .exe??
            e->acceptProposedAction();      
    }
}
```

however the `isExecutable()` function returns false for .exe files.

I have permissions to the file, and I've verified that the file path from `info` is correctly pointing to the executable.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083884/why-does-qfileinfoisexecutable-return-false-for-msi-files) makes it seem like any file with the .exe extensions should return `true`, so why is `QFileInfo::isExecutable()` returning false?

Comment: Note that only on Windows does the file name signify executableness (.exe, .com). On other systems, such as UNIX, whether or not a file is executable has nothing to do with its name, but is a seperate flag. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `QFileInfo info(e->mimeData()->urls().first().fileName()` appeared to give a valid `QFileInfo` for the executable, it wasn't actually fully working.

Using `toLocalFile()` instead of `fileName()` solved the problem.